SwiftUI ScrollView - Cancel Content Touches
Is there a way to allow a ScrollView to cancel interaction with its containing views, like we could with a UIScrollView with canCancelContentTouches?
I cannot see anything built in to let me achieve this, does anyone have a nice solution?

Doesn't it already do that? canCancelContentTouches of the underlying UIScrollView is true. I assume you have a more specific problem you want to solve? Please add more details about your specific problem.
